bluetooth pair timeout on Lenovo Y7000p2024 with Ubuntu 24.04 kerne 6.5
I recently tried to install ubuntu 22.04 on my Lenovo Y7000p2024 and everything worked fine except when I tried to connect a bluetooth keyboard and bluetooth stereo I was able to see the bluetooth devices but it never paired!
Here is the investent I have done:

About environment


Laptop: Lenovo Y7000p 2024, cpu: i-14700HX, bluetooth: rtl8852ce


Troubleshooting

- some systemd logs for bluetoothd service
******************************************************************************************
Apr 06 12:59:30 devbox systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Apr 06 12:59:30 devbox bluetoothd[4323]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Apr 06 12:59:30 devbox systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Apr 06 12:59:30 devbox bluetoothd[4323]: Starting SDP server
Apr 06 12:59:30 devbox bluetoothd[4323]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Apr 06 12:59:30 devbox bluetoothd[4323]: src/adapter.c:reset_adv_monitors_complete() **Failed to reset Adv Monitors: Failed (0x03)**
Apr 06 12:59:30 devbox bluetoothd[4323]: Failed to clear UUIDs: Failed (0x03)
Apr 06 12:59:30 devbox bluetoothd[4323]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
Apr 06 12:59:30 devbox bluetoothd[4323]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
Apr 06 12:59:30 devbox bluetoothd[4323]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
Apr 06 13:01:22 devbox bluetoothd[4323]: Failed to set mode: Not Powered (0x0f)
Apr 06 13:03:29 devbox bluetoothd[4323]: Pair device failed: Timeout (0x08)
******************************************************************************************


reinstall bluz not working


Releated Q&A
there is many related questions and anwsers if you search with "Failed to reset Adv Monitors: Failed (0x03)" many of them related to linux kernel 6.x, But I don't know if it is the same issue as I faced.

By the way, I have try to downgrade the kernel to 6.2.0, even wifi and USB keyboard will stop working (maybe the hardware is pretty new - -!). Also I try to install ubuntu 20.04, I just get a black screen....
Thanks a lot for help!

Please edit to include results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'blue|firm'

Please check your question & clarify what release you're using, your title says Ubuntu noble (what will be 24.04 on release), yet your question concentrates on 22.04, and ends with 20.04. Which are you asking about? and the 6.2 kernel which was from Ubuntu 23.04 is no longer supported being EOL; LTS releases have two main kernel choices; GA or HWE stack with HWE stack using kernels from later releases (ie. 6.2 from 23.04 but now 6.5 from 23.10, will be 6.8 next, with 5.15 being the GA kernel option)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
